# react js is not returning the list of items

Tags: reactjs

Can someone please help me with this

```
  getFriendList () {

        let friends = null;

        FB.api('/me/taggable_friends',{
            fields: 'id,name,picture',
            limit: 10,
            access_token: this.state.fbResponse.authResponse.accessToken
        }, (response) => {
            friends = response.data.map(friend => {
                return(
                    <Friend key={friend.id} />
                );
            });
        }); 

        return friends;
  };
```

It is not returning the friends list. Always returns null. please help.

I'm getting 10 data. When I do console.log, It is printing.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function

Answer (score 4):

`FB.api` is asynchronous and this is why you are getting `null` as result.

Can't you save `friends` in your state?

```
getFriendList () {
  FB.api('/me/taggable_friends',{
    fields: 'id,name,picture',
    limit: 10,
    access_token: this.state.fbResponse.authResponse.accessToken
  }, (response) => this.setState({ friends }))
}
```

I guess you are calling this method on `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.getFriendsList()
}
```

and later render friends list upon completion:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      {this.state.friends && this.state.friends.map(friend =>
        <Friend key={friend.id} />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Previously I'm using this function in render function. So I cannot use setState. Now I changed with DidMount & working.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is the [recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) place to fetch data from remote api as well described in ReactJS docs. Calling it on render is not a good practice though.